# Facebook login additional input

Tags: login, facebook-connect

I want to implement Facebook login to my project and besides the data that Facebook provides me, I'd like to request additional input from the user in order to store it in the database.

I was thinking if I could somehow ask for that specific input in the same dialog for the login, but I'm pretty sure that's not possible. Or, at least, I haven't found anything similar.

One option would be to show another modal after the login is successful, but I don't know if this is an efficient way.

The thing is this information is necessary before the users start using my app, so i can save different types of accounts. This somehow also affects the performance, because I have to make another write to the db, after the user logs in. In the classic email/password login it's just an additional checkbox that would be submitted with the form.

What do you think it would be the best achievable approach?

Comment: do you want something on the same page as the facebook login? Generally SSO-style logins will redirect the user to the facebook domain temporarily to make sure you aren't tampering with anything.

Comment: Yes, something on the same page. For example, the way Pinterest does it: http://i.imgur.com/VQwKHY6.jpg?1

And after the login they collect additional info by opening another dialogs/modals. And I was curious if there is a better solution or this approach is good enough.

Comment: That looks more like something that Facebook's login API allows, and not really a UX design thing that you have much control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do to make this less weird is that after the Facebook login is completed, on the next modal you show the user's name, profile picture and other data you gained from their Facebook account on a pre-filled form, followed by the extra input you need.

That way, your form will feel like one that is almost complete (*"look, we pre-filled everything we can, please help us by providing these little pieces of info"*), rather than a completely new and empty (albeit obviously shorter) one. They will feel like you helped them, and they will return the favor by filling in the extra input. While in the case of a *second, empty form*, they might feel that you are asking too much. (*"I've given you my Facebook already, why do you give me another form?"*)

It sounds silly, because they need to fill the exact same amount of input fields anyway, but research has shown that people are more likely to complete a loyalty card that needs 10 stamps but has 2 stamps on it already, rather than a 8-stamps one that is empty. This is because those 2 stamps would feel lost if the card wasn't completed, but on the empty one, there's nothing to lose.

Also, this approach reinforces the feeling that your registration is actually one-step (and the Facebook login is really just a way you offer the user to help them do that step), rather than making it obviously two steps.